# Validez del plural "los mapuche" sin -s final, al tratarse de una etnia

Tags: ortografía, plurales, chile

Los mapuches son la principal etnia nativa chilena, tanto en términos culturales como demográficos. A diferencia de la mayoría de los países hispanoamericanos, en Chile la proporción de habitantes culturalmente pertenecientes a etnias nativas es muy bajo (dependiendo de a quién le preguntes, entre un 4% y un 10% del total), pero el tema de la relación entre "chilenos" e indígenas es bastante importante y a veces incluso violento.

Aquí es habitual oír acerca de "**los mapuche**", sin -s, tanto en los medios masivos como a nivel oficial o académico, y tanto de boca de mapuches como de "chilenos". Pero no se trata de una aspiración de la /s/ propia del lenguaje relajado, sino de una pérdida completa y sistemática, como demuestran los siguientes ejemplos:

> [Niños mapuche de La Araucanía cumplieron sueño de conocer Palacio La Moneda gracias a CONADI](http://www.conadi.gob.cl/index.php/2-noticias/1448-ninos-mapuche-de-la-araucania-cumplieron-sueno-de-conocer-palacio-la-moneda-gracias-a-conadi) (en el sitio web oficial del Gobierno de Chile)
>
> [Red de Mujeres Mapuche de Chile](http://www.reddemujeresmapuche.cl/) (organización social)
>
> [Los mapuche en la sociedad chilena actual](https://books.google.cl/books?id=ZSTLTY3kWnwC) (un libro, entre muchos)
>
> [Libertad a los presos políticos mapuche](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AnOTdYuecLM/UlIo-7cSd6I/AAAAAAAABi4/nkyxttUwSrY/s320/umlem_mapuche.jpg) (un graffiti)

Si tú fueras y dijeras "hey, eso está mal según la ortografía de la RAE" al menos recibirías una carcajada, pero lo más probable es que causarías indignación. Yo nunca he escuchado una justificación de este plural sin -s, la verdad aquí nadie se lo pregunta. En todo caso, la forma habitual sigue siendo con -s.

¿Se explica o justifica de alguna forma esta desviación de la norma cuando se habla de etnias, o en algún otro caso?

Comment: La propia definición de "mapuche" dice "perteneciente o relativo a los mapuches", por lo que la palabra tiene un plural (no es invariable). Tal vez la justificación sea simplemente que se omite "del pueblo": "los mapuche" sería "los del pueblo mapuche", "mujeres mapuche" sería "mujeres del pueblo mapuche" y así...

Comment: Yo recuerdo haber sido enseñado que muchas de las poblaciones indígenas mantienen invariable su denominación, por lo que hablar de los mapuche no me suena raro (pero veo, al buscar con otras poblaciones, como los incas, parece ya asentada una forma plural marcada con muchas)

Comment: @guifa - desgraciadamente, no tengo explicación, pero yo digo *los inca, los maya, los quiché, los lacandón,* etc.  Así lo aprendí en México.

Comment: ¿Me atrevo a mencionar la RAE? En [_plurales_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i), el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas dice: _2.2. Nombres de tribus o etnias. No hay ninguna razón lingüística para que los nombres de tribus o etnias permanezcan invariables en plural; así pues, estas palabras formarán su plural de acuerdo con sus características formales y según las reglas generales (→ 1): los mandingas, los masáis, los mapuches, los hutus, los tutsis, los yanomamis, los bantúes, los guaraníes, los iroqueses, los patagones, los tuaregs._

Comment: mapuche significa gente de la tierra, es plural.

Comment: @sergio, _equipo_ significa "grupo de gente organizada para algo". No por eso es plural, y nadie diría _los equipo_.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Excelente aporte. Efectivamente el plural de mapuche es mapuches. Simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por lo que parece éste es un tema no investigado formalmente, de manera que todo lo que sigue es opinión mía y de otros.

Mi idea: el hecho de que se trate de una palabra de origen externo al castellano (de hecho, al indoeuropeo) quizá hizo que, para los hablantes de mapudungun por un lado y para los académicos de la lengua por el otro, resultase chocante "castellanizarla" livianamente añadiéndole una marca de plural castellana. Esto *mutatis mutandis* ocurre habitualmente en inglés con muchas palabras, no sólo etnias (aunque el hecho de que el fenómeno ocurra incluso con palabras muy comunes, típicamente con los nombres de animales gregarios, en sí mismo tiende a normalizar y hacer que se extienda la situación).

No son pocas las personas que se han hecho esta pregunta. Hay una que opina que el "respeto" por la gramática nativa del mapudungun reflejada en la no pluralización con *-s* puede [reflejar una posición pro-mapuche](http://terceracultura.cl/2013/07/los-mapuche-o-los-mapuches/) (en Chile, donde la relación entre las etnias nativas y el resto de la población ha sido siempre muy conflictiva); se apoya en datos, por supuesto muy susceptibles de sesgo, sobre el uso o no del plural *mapuches* por parte de los medios chilenos.

Sin tanta investigación y en tren decididamente prescriptivo otra persona afirma que "[si se desea respetar el bien hablar de cada idioma](http://www.renacerdeangol.cl/prontus4_noticias/site/artic/20070712/pags/20070712043303.html)" no hay que añadirle *-s* a *mapuche*. Lo cual estaría muy bien si fuese aplicable, ya que, que yo sepa, nadie declina *perestroika* o *soviet* "como debe ser", es decir, con los casos gramaticales del ruso.

Una tercera opinión, también muy prescriptiva ella, declara sin dudar que emplear *mapuche* como plural sin *-s* es siempre indicativo de una [pretendida reivindicación del mapudungun](https://holainternet.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/mapuchemapuches/). Aunque el tono es desagradable quien escribe tiene razón en un punto: en mapudungun, entre los mismos mapuche(s), el plural de *mapuche* es *pu mapuche*, expresión que sí utilizan correctamente algunos portales informativos.

Volviendo al tema de los nombres étnicos, ocurrió hace algunos años en Argentina que con el reconocimiento de ciertas comunidades nativas se comenzó a poner énfasis en los nombres empleados para referirse a ellas, donde había "problemas" más grandes que la simple pluralización. Por ejemplo, los llamados tobas dejaron de ser llamados así ya que no era su autónimo (*tová* es un peyorativo de origen guaraní); el nombre de un individuo de dicha etnia, en su propia lengua, es *[qom](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pueblo_qom)*, y así se los llama ahora oficialmente (la historia es más complicada). No se pluraliza en castellano ni tampoco se usa el plural qom. Quizá algo así haya ocurrido con *mapuche*, sólo que a partir de un proceso menos visible de revalorización de la etnia en cuestión, que (como todo proceso histórico) no está ni podría nunca estar en manos de académicos comprometidos con la neutralidad ideológica ni con la precisión lingüística.

Answer (score 5):

El plural de mapuche es **mapuches**.

La [RAE](https://www.rae.es/dpd/plural) es clara:

> Nombres de tribus o etnias. No hay ninguna razón lingüística para que
> los nombres de tribus o etnias permanezcan invariables en plural; así
> pues, estas palabras formarán su plural de acuerdo con sus
> características formales y según las reglas generales (→ 1): los
> mandingas, los masáis, **los mapuches**, los hutus, los tutsis, los
> yanomamis, los bantúes, los guaraníes, los iroqueses, los patagones,
> los tuaregs.