# ¿Qué tan crudo es un extranjerismo crudo?

Tags: ortografía, extranjerismos

En esta [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23300/17686) se referencian las indicaciones de la RAE para formar el plural de los extranjerismos crudos. En dichas referencias se puede leer:

> "Los llamados EXTRANJERISMOS CRUDOS, que conservan la pronunciación y la grafía originarias, forman el plural de acuerdo con las reglas de la lengua a la que corresponden..."

Y en [Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/los-extranjerismos-en-la-lengua-espanola-5199/)  también se puede encontrar (énfasis mío):

> Los crudos son aquellos establecidos en nuestra lengua sin perder la forma original del idioma al que pertenecen, conservando, pues, su grafía y pronunciación. [...] Para ellos la RAE estatuye la obligatoriedad de distinguirlos gráficamente, es decir, escribirlos entre comillas o en cursiva. ¿Por qué? Pues para que no quede duda de que se incorporan en su forma original y, por tanto, son ajenos a la **ortografía** y ortología del español.

Acá se menciona además la ortografía. Con esto entendería que si tomamos un extranjerismo crudo deberíamos tener en cuenta su ortografía en el idioma original, ¿verdad?

En la descripción de la RAE se presenta más adelante un ejemplo

> Así, el plural de la voz alemana *lied* ('canción') es *lieder*...

Ahora, el alemán tiene la particularidad de que todos los sustantivos se escriben con [mayúscula inicial](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Alem%C3%A1n/Gram%C3%A1tica/Sustantivos). Así, *lied* no se escribe nunca *lied* sino *Lied*. Si es un extranjerismo crudo, ¿no deberíamos traerlo tal cual como existe en su idioma original, con sus reglas de escritura y todo?

Comment: Siguiendo esa regla de tres, la palabra [_geisha_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J2awG9i) deberíamos escribirla 芸者, como en su forma original. "Geisha" no es más que una transcripción fonética de la palabra japonesa.

Comment: Iba a decir algo sobre eso pero @Charlie se me adelantó. (La transcripción fonética del japonés además sigue reglas más propias del inglés que del castellano.) Sin ir tan lejos, ¿qué es *perestroika*? La palabra es rusa pero no está en cirílico y suena como un respetable sustantivo femenino español. ¿Es un crudo o no?

Comment: Pues entonces no queda nada claro lo de _«conservan la pronunciación y la grafía originarias»_ si no vale para todos los idiomas y su propio ejemplo, como dice Mauricio, debería llevar mayúscula inicial ¿Es solo para el alfabeto latino y aplicado a las reglas que les da la gana?

Comment: En la respuesta de @pablodf76 a esta pregunta se toca el tema. [Validez del plural “los mapuche” sin -s final, al tratarse de una etnia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21055/6915)

Comment: Nadie sigue ninguna de esas reglas cuando se trata de pizzas...

Comment: Con respecto a la transcripción de nombres escritos en sistemas diferentes al alfabeto latino, Fundéu tiene una [guía](http://www.fundeu.es/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/TranscripcionesGuiaFundeu.pdf) detallada (PDF). Lo menciono para apartar eso, al menos, aunque en realidad el problema permanece (¿cuán "crudo" puede ser algo que ya ha sido "procesado" hasta el punto de utilizar una compleja guía de transliteración para volcarlo al alfabeto latino?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como ya se decía en los comentarios de la otra pregunta, la RAE un poco tira la piedra y esconde la mano, o quizá menos agresivamente podríamos decir que no reconoce sus limitaciones. La verdad es que casi todas las palabras pertenecen a la clase de los "casos particulares" que menciona la RAE como necesitados de documentación.

Ante los extranjerismos nos encontramos con dos problemas: la transliteración o transcripción, y el respeto a las reglas gramaticales de la lengua fuente. Sospecho que la inmensa mayoría de los que la RAE considera para su política son extranjerismos del inglés. Ahí habrá algún que otro plural irregular pero nada más, y no hace falta transliterar porque el alfabeto inglés es un subconjunto del latino español. Con otras lenguas romances no hay mayores problemas en cuanto a la ortografía además de acentos y cedillas, pero en el caso del italiano está el asunto de los plurales con cambio o agregado de vocal en vez de con *-s*. Con el alemán aparecen las letras con diéresis y la *ess-zet* (ß), que generalmente pueden ser transliteradas como vocal + *e* y como *ss*, respectivamente, sin provocar ambigüedad.

Un extranjerismo no latino podría ser considerado "crudo" en lo ortográfico si sigue un esquema de transcripción o transliteración. Obviamente esto depende de la definición de "crudo". Transliterar o transcribir implica un "procesamiento de datos" importante.

El problema sigue siendo la gramática. Hay categorías gramaticales, como el plural, que se pueden transferir de otra lengua al español suponiendo que uno sepa cómo hacerlo; pero hay otras que no se pueden transferir sin confusión o que no está claro cómo se podrían transferir, como los casos gramaticales. La RAE no da grandes detalles y deja entrever con su ejemplo elegido que sólo es relevante el plural, pero esto es porque número y género son las únicas categorías de flexión de los sustantivos castellanos.

El género es otro asunto espinoso pero los extranjerismos (fuera de los romances) suelen ser adoptados con un género dado arbitrario. Esto tampoco es "crudo" pero es razonable. Las lenguas eslavas tienen tres géneros, el japonés y el chino no tienen ninguno, las lenguas bantúes tienen una docena o más.

Para resumir: lo "crudo" de los extranjerismos crudos de la RAE es "bastante cocido" de hecho. Se respetan las normas de escritura "internas" a la palabra pero se impone la norma de mayúsculas/minúsculas del castellano. Se pide respetar una categoría gramatical (el plural) pero el género queda librado al azar y no hay claridad sobre qué hacer con las categorías que no se encuentran en castellano.